# Test Azure SignalR connection on server

Tags: azure, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr, azure-signalr

In an Asp.net core 3 web app, is it possible to test the server's connection to an Azure SignalR service?

Is there a recommended pattern for handling Server-to-SignalService connectivity issues such as trying to send when not connected and/or reconnecting after encountering disconnected states (if that's even possible / needed)?

Comment: Downvotes without an explanation are kind of unhelpful.  Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You can test the server's connection to an Azure SignalR Service using Azure Functions for example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service

About the connectivity:

> When the app server starts, in the background, the Azure SDK starts to
>   initiate server connections to the remote Azure SignalR. As described
>   in Internals of Azure SignalR Service, Azure SignalR routes incoming
>   client traffics to these server connections. Once a server connection
>   is dropped, all the client connections it serves will be closed too.
>
> As the connections between the app server and SignalR Service are
>   persistent connections, they may experience network connectivity
>   issues. In the Server SDK, we have Always Reconnect strategy to server
>   connections. As the best practice, we also encourage users to add
>   continuous reconnect logic to the clients with a random delay time to
>   avoid massive simultaneous requests to the server.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/blob/dev/docs/tsg.md#server-connection-drop

Comment: Ok... so it sounds like there is no direct way of looking at a connection object or property of some kind (the way you would on a raw Socket, for instance) to determine the connection state.  Sounds like it's more of a "the server sdk will do whatever can be done to maintain connectivity, so just handle exception as they occur and treat them like they will be transient").   Is that fair to say?